# using £ in function and write it to csv in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to remove pound sign from the string that is parsed from url using Beautifulsoup. And I got the following error for pound sign. 
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xa3' in file

I tried to put this `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  at the start of the class but still got the error.

This is the code. After I get the float number, I want to write it csv file.

```
    mainTag = SoupStrainer('table', {'class':'item'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp,parseOnlyThese=mainTag)
    tag= soup.findAll('td')[3]
    price = tag.text.strip()

    pr = float(price.lstrip(u'£').replace(',', ''))
```

Comment: You could replace £ with \xa3 in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely one of encoding, and bytes vs characters.  What encoding was the CSV file created with?  What sequence of bytes is in the file where the £ symbol occurs?  What are the bytes contained in the variable `price`?  You'll need to replace the bytes that actually occur in the string.  One piece of the puzzle is the contents of the data in your source code.  That's where the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` marker at the top of the source is significant:  it tells python how to interpret the bytes in a string literal.  It is possible you will need (or want) to decode the bytes from the CSV file to create a Unicode string before replacing the character.

I will point out that the [documentation for the csv module in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#module-csv) says:

> Note: This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe; see the examples in section Examples.

The examples section includes the following code demonstrating decoding the bytes provided by the csv module to Unicode strings.

```
import csv

def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                        dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
```